# How to change selected text in Qt?

Tags: qt

How can we store in `QString` only selected text, which is typed in `QTextEdit` and change it (for example `toUpper()`) and change selected by it in `QTextEdit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through the [`QTextCursor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html) API:

```
QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
if(cursor.hasSelection())
{
    cursor.insertText(cursor.selectedText().toUpper());
}
```